# bash: recursively grep and replace string

Tags: shell

I'm trying to replace all occurences of a string like `<Route component={P} path="p.html" routeName="p" />` in all files with `<Route component={L} path="'$variable_to_insert'" routeName="L"\/>` in current directory via the following script

```
VARIABLE_TO_INSERT=5


egrep -lR '<Route component={P} path="p.html" routeName="p" />' . | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 -n1 sed -i '' 's/<Route component={L} path="'$variable_to_insert'" routeName="L"\/>/g'`
```

where `$variable_to_insert` is defined earlier in the shell script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify this a bit by using `find`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | xargs sed -i "s/<Route component={P} path=\"p.html\" routeName=\"p\" \/>/<Route component={L} path=\"$VARIABLE_TO_INSERT\" routeName=\"L\" \/>/g"
#                                            |                                                      | |                                                                   |
#                                            +-------------------- replace this --------------------+ +---------------------------- with this ----------------------------+
```

Shell variables only get substituted in double-quoted strings, which is why we're doing `sed -i "s/.../.../g"`.

And note the case of `$VARIABLE_TO_INSERT` — variable names are case-sensitive.

(`-maxdepth 1` only grabs files in the current directory. You can remove it to do a recursive search for files in the current directory and all subdirectories.)

Answer (score 0):

Use $VARIABLE_TO_INSERT instead of $variable_to_insert because shell variables are case sensitive.

Also, it looks like you are missing the s///g third forward slash.